# Spring delete row of join table

Tags: mysql, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities User:

```
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long userID;

    @Column(name = "userHashedPassword")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "userName")
    private String userName;
    @Column(name = "userEmail")
    private String email;

    @Transient
    private List<String> groups = new LinkedList<>();

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "UserRoles",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                name = "userID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "roleID"))
    private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Rating> ratings;

    protected User(){}

    public User(String userHashedPassword, String userName, String email, Set<Role> roles){
        this.password = userHashedPassword;
        this.userName = userName;
        this.email = email;
        this.roles = roles;
    }
//getters and setters 
}
```

And Group:

```
@Table(name="FocusGroups")
@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator = ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class,
        property = "groupID")
public class Group {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long groupID;
    private String groupName;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "GroupMembers",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "groupID"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(
                    name = "userID"))
    private Set<User> groupMembers = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = true)
    @JoinColumn(name="frameworkID", nullable = true)
    private Framework framework;

    public Group(){}

    public Group(String groupName, Set<User> groupMembers, Framework framework) {
        this.groupName = groupName;
        this.groupMembers = groupMembers;
        this.framework = framework;
    }
//getters setters
}
```

When I delete a User, I want to remove them from group members, however it fails due to foreign key constraint: java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`capripol`.`groupmembers`, CONSTRAINT `FK98tbu0sjfsn1m5p340dn0v8wo` FOREIGN KEY (`userID`) REFERENCES `users` (`userID`))

How do I work around this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I will try to answer: First of all, it is rather strange you refer on Groups in user
entity like that:

```
@Transient
private List<String> groups = new LinkedList<>();
```

It this case, you will not have a column group in user table in database, hence you *have to* first perform removal from group_members for an all groups:

```
 delete from group_members where userid = <user_id_you_want_to_remove>;
```

And only after your JoinTable table does not contain any refers to user with <user_id_you_want_to_remove>, than you can execute

```
delete from users where userid = 1;
```

Note: there is no matter you do it by spring data (e.g. **deleteById(Long id)** and using @Query annotation specify the query above in SQL or HQL, up to you) - this will work. But I highly recommend you to reconsider you database structure - it is not cute to store only one entity.

Comment: To me it didn't seem logical to store groups in a user, but perhaps I should just store a Set of groups that they belong to for simplicity sake

Comment: All right, but if you did not - do as I mention. It will work. But you have to do all manually